# Regex - finding all 3 letter words - unexpected outcome

Tags: regex

Using regexpal.com to practice my regular expressions. I decided to start simply and ran into a problem.

Say you want to find all 3 letter words.

```
\s\w{3}\s
```

\s - space

\w - word characters

{3} - 3 and only 3 of the previous character

\s

If I have two three letter words next to each other example " and the " only the first is selected. I thought that after a regex found a match it would go back one character and start searching for the next matching string. (In which case it would "find" both " and " & " the ".

Comment: Just use word boundaries: `\b\w{3}\b`

Comment: Your regex is "eating" the whitespace. Use `\b` instead of `\s`.

Comment: @anubhava - that worked - but now it captures 3 letter words in parenthesis.

Comment: But why it shouldn't capture word in parenthesis?

Comment: @anubhava -because it's (NBA) not ( NBA ). I'm being picky here because I'm trying to improve my regex and it the details that kill you with regex.

Comment: Then you should clarify all the details in question like what you're trying to do and what it should not match. You must also add in what language/tool are you going to implement it. `regexpal.com` is good for testing but you cannot use it in your code.

Comment: @anubhava - Thx. I see that. But thx for the \b. It works in just about every use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=\s)\w{3}(?=\s)
```

Overlapping spaces.
Use 0 width assertions instead.When you use `\s\w{3}\s` on " abc acd " the regex engine consumes `abc` so the only thing left is `acd` which your regex will not match.So use `lookaround` to just assert and not consume.

EDIT:

```
\b\w{3}\b
```

Can also be used.

```
\b==>assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
```

or

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))\w{3}(?=\s|$)
```

This will find your 3 letter word even if it is at start or in middle or at end.

Comment: Using `\b` would be better, since it also matches at the beginning and end of the line.

Comment: Interesting that regexpal is not properly interpreting (?

Comment: @Mayo: regexpal only knows the javascript regex syntax, so lookbehinds are not supported. `(?<=...)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte. Thanks. I was wondering if it was a regexpal thing.