# How can I replace all the words that are exactly 3 characters long?

Tags: r

I need to replace all the words that are exactly 3 characters long with triple dots in r, and I tried this:

```
myText <- "How are you today?"
gsub ('\\w{3}','...',myText)
```

But the result is: "... ... ... ay?"
How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you need to include the word boundaries: `gsub("\\b\\w{3}\\b", "...", myText)`. A similar [reference for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28305164/5977215)